# How can I switch to root user and source a different user's .bashrc in one command

Tags: bash, shell

My reason is to so I can be root but still use the aliases from my normal user's .bashrc file into a bash script.  So far I've tried

sudo -s && source /home/normaluser/.bashrc

but this will not source the .bashrc until I switch back to the normal user.

Comment: I think it's because && will not pass the execution context to the next command. Try: sudo sh -c 'source /home/normaluser/.bashrc && exec bash'

Answer (score 0):

After I read the man pages again for sudo I realized I missed the -E preserve environment flag but I'm still confused on how to implement it into a bash script.

when I tried to add

sudo -sE

it seems to change the user as well as pause the script until I exited root.

Comment: Hello, i dont understand what you want, sudo -sE opens an interactive shell, its like sudo bash -i. When you insert this line in a script, an interactive shell is started and the script continues with the next line after you exit the interactive shell. There is nothing magic about it. If you want to start a script as root and with bashrc of a certain user as source then insert in your script source /home/normaluser/.bashrc and start your script with sudo ./yourscript, if you want an interactive shell as root, with environment variable of the user before then use sudo -sE